# How to parse JSON to display in a Rails View?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

I'm just trying to do a quick currency conversion using the Google API and display just the "rate" information in a rails view using either jQuery or a Rails method.

The returned JSON is in this format:

```
{"to": "EUR", "rate": 0.74928817599999997, "from": "USD"}
```

So far I have tried a jQuery Ajax request as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('#exchange');
});
});
```

I don't actually need the items array or the unordered list. I have just copied most of this from the jQuery documentation to ensure it should be working.

I would appreciate any help with this code or if there is a better Rails-way to implement the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok that you make a query to Google API from rails in your server (not from javascript inside browser) then use

```
 @result=JSON.parse(response_body_as_string)
```

@result will be a Ruby hash object which you can use in the Rails view as you wish.

If you plan to sonnect to Google API from server, better you do it as a background job and save the result to a database for next one hour.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this on the server side? I am quite inexperienced at using apis and rails. If is is impossible to do via jsonp and json I don't understand how anyone could actually make use of the api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonp to make the request if you want to do it on the client (normal HTTP requests are not allowed via JavaScript across different hosts):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data) {
    $('#yourId').html(data.rate); // populate the HTML element with id 'yourId' with the rate
  }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works with the google api. jsonp may not be supported. and how would I display the rate result in a html view?

Comment: Hey user2514224, I have tried that code against the API, and it does log the result. I'll amend the code so that it populates an element with a given id.